# Why Expanded widget can not add a child which is Text in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I add a Expanded widget whose child is Text into a list,Android Studio throw a error message like this:
Error: The argument type 'Expanded' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Text'.

```
final List<Text> words = [];
words.add(Expanded(child: Text('hello')));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeYWK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is a List of Text widget and you are trying to add an Expanded widget to it.

try this:

```
final List<Expanded> words = [];
words.add(Expanded(child: Text('hello')));
```

or:

```
final List<Text> words = [];
words.add(Text('hello'));
```

or:

```
final List<Widget> words = [];
words.add(Expanded(child: Text('hello')));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` is a widget that can be used with(inside) Row, Column and Flex. You can't add it to a list of type `Text`, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final List<Text> words = [];
words.add(Text('hello'));
```